# does Meteor ReactiveArray have $addToSet equivalent?

Tags: meteor, push

Does Meteor ReactiveArray have $addToSet equivalent?  I'm using push, but boy addToSet would be useful!

Comment: I believe `ReactiveArray` is not part of Meteor but is from a package. Which one are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/ManuelDeLeon/ReactiveArray

Comment: https://github.com/ManuelDeLeon/ReactiveArray